# PHP If statement in input tag value, and form not processing

Tags: php

My form isn't processing.  Once I've entered details or even if not, I'm getting the else statement echo "Your password reset key is invalid" on line 95.  The key is correct but...

I think there's an issue with the if statement on lines 160-164 for the value of the input tag.  I think it needs wrapping in a php tag, but am not sure what's wrong...?

Hope someone can help.  Thanks.

```
<?php

$objForm = new Form();
$objValid = new Validation($objForm);
$objUser = new User();


// Was the form submitted?
if (isset($_POST["ResetPasswordForm"]))
{

        // Form Fields Check
        if ($objForm->isPost('email')) {

            $objValid->_expected = array(
            'email',
            'password',
            'confirm_password'

            );

            $objValid->_required = array(
                'email',
                'password',
                'confirm_password'

                );


            $objValid->_special = array(
                'email' => 'email'
                );


            $objValid->_post_remove = array(
                'confirm_password'
                );


            $objValid->_post_format = array(
                'password' => 'password'
                );

            $email = $objForm->getPost('email');
            $user = $objUser->getByEmail($email);

            if (empty($user)) {
                $objValid->add2Errors('e-mail_not_found');
            }

        }


    // Gather the post data
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $confirmpassword = $_POST["confirmpassword"];
        $hash = $_POST["q"];    


    // validate password
    $password = $objForm->getPost('password');
    $confirmpassword = $objForm->getPost('confirmpassword');

    if (!empty($password) && !empty($confirmpassword) && $password != $confirmpassword) {
        $objValid->add2Errors('password_mismatch');
    }

    // Use the same salt from the forgot_password.php file
    $salt = "---blank for demo---";

    // Generate the reset key
    $resetkey = hash('sha512', $salt.$email);

    // Does the new reset key match the old one?
    if ($resetkey == $hash)
    {
        if ($password == $confirmpassword)
        {
            //hash and secure the password
            $password = hash('sha512', $password);

            // Update the user's password
                $query = $conn->prepare('UPDATE clients SET password = :password WHERE email = :email');
                $query->bindParam(':password', $password);
                $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
                $query->execute();
                $conn = null;
            Helper::redirect('/?page=password_changed');
        }
        else
            $objValid->add2Errors('password_mismatch');
    }
    else
        echo "Your password reset key is invalid.";
}


require_once('_header.php'); ?>

<div id="cat_prod"><h1>- CHANGE PASSWORD -</h1></div>

    <br /><br />


    <form action="" method="POST">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tbl_insert">

            <tr>

                <th>
                    <label for="email">E-mail : *</label>
                </th>

                <td>
                    <?php echo $objValid->validate('e-mail_not_found'); ?>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="login_email" class="fld" 
                    value="<?php echo $objForm->stickyText('e-mail_not_found'); ?>" /> 
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>
                    <label for="password">Password : *</label>      
                </th>

                <td>
                    <?php echo $objValid->validate('password'); ?>
                    <?php echo $objValid->validate('password_mismatch'); ?>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="fld" value="" />
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <th>
                    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password : *</label>      
                </th>

                <td>
                    <?php echo $objValid->validate('confirm_password'); ?>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="comfirm_password" class="fld" value="" />
                </td>

            </tr>


            <tr>

                <th>
                     
                </th>

                <td>
                    <label for="change_pass" class="sbm_blue fl_l">
                    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="';
                                if (isset($_GET["q"])) {                        
                                echo $_GET["q"];                            
                            }                           
                                echo '" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ResetPasswordForm" id="btn_login" class="btn" value=" Reset Password " />
                    </label>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>

    </form>


<?php require_once('_footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your code? Are you getting any error messages? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Are you sure the values are getting passed from one part of the page to another ?

Comment: How do you know the values are the same? It looks like the `q` will have raw PHP in it. That should be in php blocks. `value="';
                                if (isset($_GET["q"])) {                        
                                echo $_GET["q"];                            
                            }                           
                                echo '" />`

Comment: I added `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of my page but don't get anything showing.

Comment: chris, the q is a static string that never changes, it is a hash of the $salt and $email that is sent via e-mail to a user for changing their password.  I need to update this and implement a token system for temp links, but that's to be done.  I have been merging two pages to get this working on one as I had some validation messages to output via objValid and the Validation class, so previously I was simply wrapping the form in `<?php echo ' ' ;?>` which worked... but now that doesn't with my merging code.

Comment: You have to put that echo in php blocks.. Also this can make your page open to XSS injection. A malicious user could link to the page with `q` containing markup to insert a form.

Comment: Which echo do you mean in a php block?  I've tried but still the form doesn't process.  Yes, re XSS, i'll be updating as  say to that token system asap to randomise the string - i.e. have temp links and string in database auto-updating on use.

Comment: In the input field, from first comment.

Comment: Yep, already tried that and get notice and fatal errors as mentioned in the answer/comments below.  No joy.

Comment: Please update your code. Where is `$conn` defined?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps it should be conndb? as I have that in my DBase class... `private function connect() {
  $this->_conndb = mysql_connect($this->_host, $this->_user, $this->_password);`  Strange as I say though that this worked when form simply wrapped, I've just added other if conditions to validate passwords, check and report errors.  I'm using Object Oriented PHP and extending classes.

Comment: Cool, I added this back in that I removed as the database connection should d be run automatically for each of my pages, so something's up with that...  `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you have some typo. Try it like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["q"]) ? $_GET["q"]: '' ;?>"/>
```

Comment: She'll have to escape those double quotes.

Comment: I know the if statement is correct as it previously worked when I wrapped the form, so yes maybe something is up...?  Doing it your way I just get a fatal error... `Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /reset_password.php on line 84

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /reset_password.php on line 84`

Btw, I'm Male :)  Blame the parents... Lol

Comment: Escaping the quotes renders the page blank.

Comment: in a case of Call to a member function prepare() you just have no connection object ready. And you don't need escape quotes, to check it out see the source of you page

Comment: can you do  echo print_r($conn, true); before line $query = $conn->prepare(....  just to see if there is an object

Comment: so you have no connection, check the code where you creating the connection, It could be that the server is down